# I am unable to load data from my custom package's database in to my running project(project is running in docker), it shows me following error

Tags: django

I have a custom package name "xyz", i installed it in my project running in docker, but its unable to load data from databse of package "xyz",
it show me following error.
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "xyz" does not exist

even while executing makemigrations and migrate command, it shows a same error
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "xyz" does not exist
although i have intial migrations file in my docker container.

how i can access my database of my package.?

i try makemigrations and migrate command, but same error.